# Scaling database for millions of records

Tags: database, nosql, scalability

We are developing an application that processes some codes and output large amount of rows each time (millions !). We want to save these rows in a database because the processing itself make take a couple of hours to complete.

**1. What is the best way to save these records ?**

**2.  is a NoSql solution usable here ?**

Assume that we are saving five million records per day, and may be retrieving from it once in a while.

Comment: where from u r retrieving data,from file system or what?

Comment: Sure, NoSQL could be a solution. So could a regular DB. 5M isn't that much.

Comment: I am retrieving the input from relational database. Now my question is, where do we store it.

Comment: Just to put it out there, 5 million rows isnt really that much data, a regular relational database will cope fine with that volume of data. Some of my dev databases running on my desktop pc have around 20M rows and its no problem

Answer (score 2):

It depends very much on how you intend to use the data after it is generated. If you will only be looking it up by primary key then NoSQL will probably be fine, but if you ever want to search or sort the data (or join rows together) then an SQL database will probably work better.

Basically, NoSQL is really good at stuffing opaque data into a store and retrieving any individual item very quickly. Relational databases are really good at indexing data that may be joined together or searched.

Any modern SQL database will easily handle 5 million rows per day - disk space is more likely to be your bottleneck, depending on how big your rows are. I haven't done a lot with NoSQL, but I'd be surprised if 5 million items per day would cause a problem.

Comment: Re: noSQL - a single Apache Cassandra node can handle around a billion writes per day - if that's not enough then add more nodes to the cluster ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on exactly what kind of data you want to store - could you elaborate on that? If the data is neatly structured into tables then you don't necessarily need a NoSQL approach. If, however, your data has a graph or network-like structure to it, then you should consider a NoSQL solution. If the latter is true for you, then maybe the following will be helpful to give you an overview of some of the NoSQL databases: http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis